# Doubts in Oracle index

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
 Tran_id         Tran_name     Tran_region     Tran_Date    Tran_Item 
    1             Tanya         Europe          04-FEB-16    book
    2             Tanya         Europe          04-FEB-16    book1
    3             Tanya         Europe          04-FEB-16    book2
    4             Tanya         Europe          04-FEB-16    book3
```

For this table am creating an Index as Index(Tran_region,Tran_date)

Lets assume there are one million rows in my test table

I need to fetch the records based on Tran_name='Tanya' , Tran_region='Europe', Tran_date='04-Feb-16'

My Oracle Query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEST_TABLE 
WHERE Tran_name='Tanya' , Tran_region='Europe', Tran_date='04-Feb-16'
```

How the index will run for my query, will it go for full table scan or scan based on the indexed columns

As I created the index for the column Tran_region, Tran_date but in my where clause I specified the tran_name also which is not indexed.

Appreciate if anyone provide the index functionality working principal. I am new to Oracle technologies.

Comment: Check the execution plan: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9010.htm#SQLRF01601

Answer (score 1):

If you ran that query it'll just throw an error as it is invalid.

You don't *really* know what it will do until you run it. It might choose not to use the index for a bizarre reason. But it will probably use your index since you are searching on leading columns of the index. If another index existed with *all* of those columns (a covering index) it would probably use that instead.

If another index existed that was missing one of those as a leading column, it might do a skip scan on that one instead.

It's the order of columns in the *index*, not the order of columns in the `where` that matters.

Comment: So the oracle wont do the full table scan rite, Only based on the index it will scan. Correct me if am wrong

Comment: Yes it's highly unlikely it will do a full table scan